# HTTP Errors with .Net 3.5 SP1

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a ASP.Net website that is failing on AJAX postbacks (both with ASP.Net AJAX and a 3rd part control) in IE.    FireFox works fine.  If I install the website on another machine without .Net 3.5 SP1, it works as expected.

When it fails, Fiddler shows that I'm getting a 405 "Method Not Allowed".  The form seems to be posting to pages other than page I'm viewing.

The form's action is "#" for the page on the broken website (with SP1).  The form's action is "Default.aspx" for the same page on a website without SP1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP1 changes the HtmlForm control so that it honors the action attribute, where previous versions ignored it.  It sounds like you have something like this on the broken pages:

```
<form runat="server" action="#">
```

Remove the action, and it should be fine:

```
<form runat="server">
```

More info here:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1305800.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following Microsoft Knowledge base article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216493

If you're using IIS4 or IIS5 this may be the problem.